# Saving I/O pins of a micro controller by using Matrix Key pad

Tags: interface, microcontroller

There are many ways to save I/O pins of a micro controller. But I didn't understand how a matrix key pad helps to save I/O pins of a micro controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 16-button keyboard, you can construct it so each key is wired to a pin - 16 input pins.

But if you have a matrix, 4 rows x 4 columns, that is only 8 pins (4 out and 4 in) to address 16 buttons.

You active each row pin in turn and look at the input from the 4 columns pins, which can be done with a single read (for each row). That will tell you if there are any key closures on that row.

You then iterate through the columns to find out which bit is set (it might be more then one) then use a lookup table based on `row * 4 + col` to translate the row and column data to, say, an ASCII value such `'1'`.

Quite often, such devices are wired with inverse logic, so the outputs and/or inputs might have the BAR sense, i.e. active-zero.